# Simple IF then multiply VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have a table such as the image above and I just want to have a simple code where if the ID is equal to each other, (1=1) then it will return another set of rows on the bottom (Answer) that will show

```
answer = price * (1 + discount)
```

Comment: Please post the actual code as text, not a link to an image!

Comment: I don't have a code yet. @KenY-N it's a really simple table but I'm not sure what to use

Comment: Why does this even need to be VBA?  Can't you just use a `SUMIFS` multiplied by another `SUMIFS`?

Comment: @YowE3K I'm doing a more complicated piece, but I just need to simplify it as I am not very good in VBA

Comment: is there any reason why `ID/fruit/price/discount/answer` are not column names  .... and `1/apple/500/5%/525` are not in one row ???

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Answer` will appear below `Price` and `Discount`, following should be helpful.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim dictPrice As Object, dictDiscount As Object
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")      'change Sheet1 to your data sheet
    Set dictPrice = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictDiscount = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'get last row with data using Column A
        For Each cel In .Range("A2:A" & lastRow)            'loop though all cells in Column A
            If cel.Value = "Price" Then                     'check if its Price
                dictPrice.Add cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, cel.Offset(0, 3).Value    'add id and correspoding price in dictionary
            ElseIf cel.Value = "Discount" Then              'check if its Discount
                dictDiscount.Add cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, cel.Offset(0, 3).Value 'add id and correspoding discount in dictionary
            ElseIf cel.Value = "Answer" Then                'check if its Answer
                cel.Offset(0, 3).Value = dictPrice(cel.Offset(0, 1).Value) * (1 + dictDiscount(cel.Offset(0, 1).Value))
            End If
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

***Note :*** `If cel.Value = "Price" Then` is case-sensitive match and will match only `Price` and not `price` and same applies to `ElseIf cel.Value = "Discount" Then` and `ElseIf cel.Value = "Answer" Then`.

Comment: Good one Mrig! +1 You beat me to it. I was about to post the similar answer, though using Arrays. :)

Comment: @sktneer - Even array is good option here, probably you should post it as answer.

Comment: I derived a solution using Dictionary and Array and as I said I was about to post it when I saw that you already posted the similar answer except I used arrays instead of range variable so discarded the file without saving it. Lol